# Why is it from high to low if we show a decimal

Tags: education

From my experience, when we give a range we usually go from lowest to highest.

EG, from 1 to 10

I was reading about mosquitoes and saw this

> The average mosquito bite drains 0.01 to 0.001 milliliters of blood.

Sorry if this is off topic, maybe English stack exchange site is better for this but... Is this normal? Are decimals (as a range) usually referred to highest to lowest?

My own googling shows nothing around this

Comment: I would say it is (much) more typical to define a range by starting with the lower number.

Comment: Can I ask why it is spam? I have no links, I've been a member for years.. @szw1710 and the other site I refer to is part of the stack exchange

Comment: This is my personal opinion I used the voting form and I don't know why it appereed here. I agree, such opinion should not be seen here.

Comment: This is definitely not spam; if somebody flagged this as spam, then they did so by mistake.

Comment: The quoted text about mosqitos is simply the typo. There is no a deep reason to consider it here. But... I repeat, this is my personal opinion,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What was written is possibly unintentional. Though I don't think I would call it wrong, it's far more common to start a range with a lower number, regardless of whether the numbers are greater than $1$. But there are some occasions when lower implies "more," like with negative temperatures, which might be listed as a range in the opposite order. In this case though I would've written $0.001$ to $0.01$.